# Xcode Scrollview wrong constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I designed a UI in Xcode with a ScrollView and added constraints to it. In Interface designer it looks as I want, but running it with the simulator causes a big spacing at the right side of the ContentView inside the ScrollView.

Here are two pics to show what I mean

[image] 
[image]

So what did I do wrong here?

Thanks for your helping hand

## Solution

The ContentView needed the same width than the View. So select both, go to your constraints and select "Equal Widths".

Comment: try making Content View width equal to View width

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as though you haven't added constraints to the scroll view  (ScrollViewer) to pin its edges to its parent view (View).

Comment: well there are constraints, and the Scrollview was not the problem, but thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue after updating to xcode 8+. ScrollView started to act strange. For now I am adding constrains from inside scrollView to another view witch isn't in scrollView itself (like leading, trailing) to mainView.